# How does a bob oscillating tied at the end of rope obey the law of energy conservation?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

A bob which has earned a certain potential energy being lifted and displaced from its equilibrium position.  Then how does it oscillate back and fro to give so much energy.  Or how can a little change of potential energy give such a big amount of energy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it does not gain any more energy than the initial potential energy.Its the same energy changing forms.At the bottom point it will be completely kinetic energy and at the top it will be completely potential energy.Thats why, if resistence(dissipation) is present, it loses the energy slowly and comes to rest after some time.

Comment: I am asking if I put on a certain amount of work once how can I get back great amount of energy.  I have put mgh energy.  Then I get mghn energy back . n= number of positions.

Comment: Just because an object moves continuously, it doesnt mean the energy is added up.For instance if take a flywheel and give it a rotation, the work done by you is Torque*angular displacement.If there is no friction in the bearings, the fly wheel will continuously rotate.Does it mean the flywheel gains energy?If you connect the flywheel to a load, it will do the same amount of work you gave it as input.

Answer (score 1):

> Or how can a little change of potential energy give such a big amount
>   of energy?

It doesn't. The problem is here:

> I have put mgh energy. Then I get mghn energy back . n= number of
>   positions.

You did not get any "energy back" in this case. **You** got zero energy back.

To get "energy back" you would have to do something to the bob, like touch it. When you do so, the bob will stop. I assure you that the amount of energy it transfers to your finger will be mgh.

Even if you don't touch it, in the real world you'll see the bob slow down and eventually stop. This is due largely to losses due to air friction and similar effects. The amount of energy lost in this process is... mgh.

I think you're getting confused because you see the energy of the motion, which is obvious just looking at it, but not the potential energy, which is invisible. So you see one and not the other that balances it out.